# how to solve nil error in rspec

Tags: rspec

hii,

I have a problem that a nil error.My controller code is like this

```
def list
  @users=User.find(params[:id])

  if (@users.servers.count>0)
    puts 'more than one'
  else
    puts 'equal or less than one'
  end
end
```

My Rspec code is

```
it'should_test_list' do
  @user_mock=mock(User)
  User.should_receive(:find).and_return(@user_mock)
  @user_mock.should_receive(servers).and_return(@user_mock.servers)
  @user_mock.servers.should_receive(:count).and_return(1)
end
```

I am getting warning that `@user_mock.servers` is nil

one more thing I want to ask that Is this right way for this probelm??

I am waiting for reply

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stubbed the `servers` method on the `User` mock, so the spec cannot continue from that point. Fix it like so:

`@user_mock.stub(:servers).and_return([mock])`. Or add it when the mock is created.

Also, your spec never calls the controller action. You need a `get :list`. Example:

```
describe UsersController do
  it 'should list' do
    @user_mock = mock(User,:servers=>[mock])
    User.should_receive(:find).and_return(@user_mock)
    @user_mock.servers.should_receive(:count).and_return(1)
    get :list, :id => 1
  end
end
```

One last note: I'm assuming in `@users = User.find(params[:id])` you really meant `@user`, since only one row is being returned.